# Add file to multipart form request in IntelliJ HTTP Client

Tags: rest, http, intellij-idea

I am attempting to POST an HTTP request to [the Mindee API](https://mindee.com/) using IntelliJ IDEA's HTTP client. Specifically, I want to upload an image of a receipt. According to [the documentation](https://platform.mindee.net/apishub/products/expense_receipts?setup=default#documentation), the form data must have the form

```
{ file: your_file }
```

So my question is...how do I specify the field name for a file in IntelliJ's HTTP client? What is the syntax?

I've tried a few different things with similar results. I get

```
POST https://api.mindee.net/products/expense_receipts/v3/predict

HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
Date: Mon, 01 Feb 2021 22:18:15 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 84
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx/1.15.12
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

{
  "details": {
    "file": [
      "This field is required."
    ]
  },
  "message": "Invalid fields in form"
}
```

Here are two of my attempts:

```
POST https://api.mindee.net/products/expense_receipts/v3/predict
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; bundary=boundary
X-Inferuser-Token: <my token>
{
    file: < /path/to/image.jpg
}
```

```
POST https://api.mindee.net/products/expense_receipts/v3/predict
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; bundary=boundary
X-Inferuser-Token: <my token>

--boundary

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
< /path/to/image.jpg

--boundary--
```

The second seemed the most promising since it took longer to return a response, but I still got the same thing.

Comment: I don't have access to the documentation, so I can only guess. I assume that the second request is supposed to work. Both requests have a typo in them - `bundary` instead of `boundary`, could it be the culprit here?

Comment: @EugeneMorozov Thanks for the eagle eyes. Took me like 5 tries to find the error you meant. That seems to fix the problem.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov And the documentation for this Mindee API isn't actually important for this question. I'm just using that as an example to illustrate. The real question is about the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second attempt request should work okay, but you have a typo in there - `bundary` instead of `boundary`.